# Vim-Matlab plugin

Tags: neovim, matlab

I am trying to get the plugin [vim-matlab](https://github.com/daeyun/vim-matlab) for neovim working, but with no success. When I try to call any command from nvim ( like `:MatlabCliHelp` ), I get the following output. Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you for your answers

```
Error detected while processing function remote#define#CommandBootstrap[5]..remote#define#request:
line    2:                                                                                                                                                                                        
error caught in request handler '/home/kuntik/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-matlab/rplugin/python/vim_matlab:command:MatlabCliHelp ()':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kuntik/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-matlab/rplugin/python/vim_matlab/__init__.py", line 121, in matlab_cli_help
    self.activate_cli()
  File "/home/kuntik/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-matlab/rplugin/python/vim_matlab/__init__.py", line 81, in activate_cli
    self.cli_controller = MatlabCliController()
  File "/home/kuntik/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-matlab/rplugin/python/vim_matlab/matlab_cli_controller.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.connect_to_server()
  File "/home/kuntik/.config/nvim/bundle/vim-matlab/rplugin/python/vim_matlab/matlab_cli_controller.py", line 20, in connect_to_server
    self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to connect to the server, but it looks like the server just isn't running...

See the plug-in's [usage](https://github.com/daeyun/vim-matlab/blob/master/README.md#usage), which tells you how you need to start the server first, with:

```
./scripts/vim-matlab-server.py
```

From the README file:

> This will start a Matlab REPL and redirect commands received from Vim to Matlab. When Matlab crashes (e.g. segfault during MEX development), it will launch another process.
>
> Then open Vim in another terminal and start editing .m files.
>
> Alternatively, launch a server instance from Vim using `:MatlabLaunchServer`. The server will be launched either in a Neovim terminal buffer or a tmux split (see `g:matlab_server_launcher`).

So starting it with a `:MatlabLaunchServer` command seems to be an option too.

Comment: It seems I had isue with automatic installation ( all scripts that supposed to be installed were missing). That is probably the reason why :MatalbLaunchServer command is missing in my neovim. Anyway I fixed the problem with maualy adding scripts to my scripts folder. 
Thank you for your time.